# Efficient way to compute Jacobian x Jacobian.T

Tags: python, pytorch, backpropagation, autograd, jax

Assume `J` is the Jacobian of some function `f` with respect to some parameters. Are there efficient ways (in PyTorch or perhaps Jax) to have a function that takes two inputs (`x1` and `x2`) and computes `J(x1)*J(x2).transpose()` *without* instantiating the entire `J` matrices in memory?

I have come across something like `jvp(f, input, v=vjp(f, input))` but don't quite understand it and not sure is what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JAX, you can compute a full jacobian matrix using `jax.jacfwd` or `jax.jacrev`, or you can compute a jacobian operator and its transpose using `jax.jvp` and `jax.vjp`.

So, for example, say you had a function `Rᴺ → Rᴹ` that looks something like this:

```
import jax.numpy as jnp
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1701)
N, M = 10000, 5
f_mat = np.array(np.random.rand(M, N))
def f(x):
  return jnp.sqrt(f_mat @ x / N)
```

Given two vectors `x1` and `x2`, you can evaluate the Jacobian matrix at each using `jax.jacfwd`

```
import jax
x1 = np.array(np.random.rand(N))
x2 = np.array(np.random.rand(N))
J1 = jax.jacfwd(f)(x1)
J2 = jax.jacfwd(f)(x2)
print(J1 @ J2.T)
# [[3.3123782e-05 2.5001222e-05 2.4946943e-05 2.5180108e-05 2.4940484e-05]
#  [2.5084497e-05 3.3233835e-05 2.4956826e-05 2.5108084e-05 2.5048916e-05]
#  [2.4969209e-05 2.4896170e-05 3.3232871e-05 2.5006309e-05 2.4947023e-05]
#  [2.5102483e-05 2.4947576e-05 2.4906987e-05 3.3327218e-05 2.4958186e-05]
#  [2.4981882e-05 2.5007204e-05 2.4966144e-05 2.5076926e-05 3.3595043e-05]]
```

But, as you note, along the way to computing this 5x5 result, we instantiate two 5x10,000 matrices. How might we get around this?

The answer is in `jax.jvp` and `jax.vjp`. These have somewhat unintuitive call signatures for the purposes of your question, as they are designed primarily for use in forward-mode and reverse-mode automatic differentiation. But broadly, you can think of them as a way to compute `J @ v` and `J.T @ v` for a vector `v`, without having to actually compute `J` explicitly.

For example, you can use `jax.jvp` to compute the effect of `J1` operating on a vector, without actually computing `J1`:

```
J1_op = lambda v: jax.jvp(f, (x1,), (v,))[1]

vN = np.random.rand(N)
np.allclose(J1 @ vN, J1_op(vN))
# True
```

Similarly, you can use `jax.vjp` to compute the effect of `J2.T` operating on a vector, without actually computing `J2`:

```
J2T_op = lambda v: jax.vjp(f, x2)[1](v)[0]

vM = np.random.rand(M)
np.allclose(J2.T @ vM, J2T_op(vM))
# True
```

Putting these together and operating on an identity matrix gives you the full jacobian matrix product that you're after:

```
def direct(f, x1, x2):
  J1 = jax.jacfwd(f)(x1)
  J2 = jax.jacfwd(f)(x2)
  return J1 @ J2.T

def indirect(f, x1, x2, M):
  J1J2T_op = lambda v: jax.jvp(f, (x1,), jax.vjp(f, x2)[1](v))[1]
  return jax.vmap(J1J2T_op)(jnp.eye(M)).T

np.allclose(direct(f, x1, x2), indirect(f, x1, x2, M))
# True
```

Along with the memory savings, this indirect method is also a fair bit faster than the direct method, depending on the sizes of the jacobians involved:

```
%time direct(f, x1, x2)
# CPU times: user 1.43 s, sys: 14.9 ms, total: 1.44 s
# Wall time: 886 ms
%time indirect(f, x1, x2, M)
# CPU times: user 311 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 311 ms
# Wall time: 158 ms
```